# Make Navigation accessible for text readers

Tags: html, list, navigation, html-lists, accessibility

([navigation layout picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyVB6.png))

I have the navigation-layout of tabs and sub-tabs, which i want to make accessible via text-reader/lynx. It consists of the main pages "Startseite", "Über", "Interessant", "Orte", as well as the sub-pages "Linköping", "München" and "Baustelle". The logical structure would thus be:

- Startseite
- Über
- Interessant

  - Linköping
  - München
  - Baustelle
- Orte

But since I use a layout of several div-tags, it only yields this in lynx:

Startseite
Über
Interessant
Linköping
München
Baustelle
Orte

The questions (or solutions I don't know how to implement yet) now are:

(1) how do I improve my layout to make it accessible via text-reader/lynx 
 ... or 
(2) how do I adjust a layout of unorderd lists and sub-lists (see code) too look like my current tabbed navigation-layout?

```
    <nav>
    <ul id="mainpages">
        <li><a href="./">Startseite</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">Über</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">Interessant</a>
                <ul id="sub1">
                    <li><a href="./">Linköping</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./">München</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./">Baustelle</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="./">Orte</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

keep in mind that my main tasks is making it text-reader/lynx accessible. I though of using a layout like this, since it is easily styled with #some_ul_id {display: inline-block}:

```
    <nav>
    <ul id="mainpages">
        <li><a href="./">Startseite</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">Über</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">Interessant</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">Orte</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="sub1">
        <li><a href="./">Linköping</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">München</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">Baustelle</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My third question is:

(3) Is this good practice? Should I do it?

It is the easiest way, though solution (2) would be nicer, since it is more logical.

Comment: Are you really only looking to support lynx, or do you need to support NVDA, VoiceOver, JAWS etc.? If you need to support lynx, do you also need to support Orca?

Comment: Really curious why you are targeting lynx instead of some of the more current screenreaders that unobf mentions; no good reason for using it unless you have some very specific reason for doing so. Your code looks fine as-is and is semantically correct; I'd be wary of changing it for sake of compat with a tool that's not even mentioned [in a recent 2014 web screen reader survey](http://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey5/#primary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this could be to absolutely position the sub-menu – of course that requires that you know beforehand that there’ll be enough space, so that items don’t go over multiple lines (resp. you have an alternative at hand for smaller screens via media queries).

So you would position the outer `ul` (or the `nav` itself) `relative`, and then on `:hover` over a main menu item you make the sub-`ul` visible, that is positioned absolutely in such a way that it comes to lay underneath the line of main menu items – like this: http://jsfiddle.net/0rpyLqtn/

Other slight variations are easily imaginable; if you don’t want “blank space” underneath the single line of main menu items, you could f.e. give that `ul` a `border-bottom` instead of a `margin-bottom`, and have the border color of it visible at all times, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/0rpyLqtn/1/

---

Since you have accessibility in mind, you might also want to pay attention to how this kind of menu behaves on devices that do not have a “mouse” as input device. Getting such a menu to be accessible via keyboard can be tricky, and on touchscreens a menu based on `:hover` might not work that well either. Anyhow, such issues have been discussed on the net already, so with a little research you should be able to find solutions/workarounds for these issues as well.

Comment: Thank you a lot! The page is only static. I personally don't like drop down menus, because they are hard to navigate. I imagined it to be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/0rpyLqtn/5/

Comment: I don't see how this helps lynx users - it doesn't seem to change anything for those users (if any exist); and introducing :hover makes things *worse* from an accessibility viewpoint since you then have to add keyboard/ARIA support - which was not an issue in the original...

Answer (score 1):

From an accessibility perspective, the way to markup the solution so that it semantically represents what you are trying to achieve is to use the WAI-ARIA `menubar`, `menu` and the various `menuitem` roles. You should also use the `aria-haspopup="true"` attribute to show sub-menus and the `aria-expanded` attribute to track when the menu is expanded. In order to achieve the semantic markup of the hierarchy, you will want to have hierarchical lists as this is the easiest way to represent the hierarchy in an understandable way.

Here is a link to a full dynamic ARIA menu example http://dylanb.github.io/bower_components/a11yfy/examples/menu.html

You will need to ensure that each menu item is keyboard focusable using an href attribute on an anchor tag will do this for you as long as you look for the 'click' event and don't do anything funky with mousedown/mouseup etc.